# How to implement fastest api call in node js?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server, alexa-sdk-nodejs

I tired to implement crud Operation in node js using mongodb.I have 5000 data in mongodb.In data i have lot of images.first time i tried to using get data to show all 5000 datas.but its showing 50s delay to show the data.how to show data without delay.give me solution

Answer (score -1):

Sending whole data might be a problem in some cases, to solve this we can send data to some limit or according to client requirements. Pagination rectifies this to some extent, it limits and skips the data as per your needs.
Take a look at this [link](https://codeforgeek.com/server-side-pagination-using-node-and-mongo/) to know how to use it.